# In maven execute a build plugin as defined in a dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a pom which has a bunch of plugins with some particular configurations.

For example under build plugins I specify the output location of the jar and also run the maven-dependency-plugin with some specific options in order to create the wanted result, for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/${project.version}/libs</outputDirectory>
                <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/${project.version}/libs</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also have some plugins under profiles.

I would like to move the plugin configurations to a different pom.xml so that I can have one pom.xml that knows about the plugin configurations while many other projects can depend on that pom to make use of those configured plugins.

Ideally that one pom with the plugin configurations would not be a parent to all other projects.

Comment: Do you like to create an executable jar?

Comment: To share plugin configuration, the POM need to be a parent.